# VK API поиск записей по слову (Android)

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Ничего не возвращает следующий запрос:

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("newsfeed.search", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1, VKApiConst.FIELDS, "id", VKApiConst.Q, "конкурс", VKApiConst.COUNT, 20));
```

Весь код:

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("newsfeed.search", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1, VKApiConst.FIELDS, "id", VKApiConst.Q, "конкурс", VKApiConst.COUNT, 20));

request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);
        list = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
```

`NullPointerException` для этого запроса, хотя для других запросов нет исключений.

Как можно прописать правильно? Спасибо.